# Secure, "Downloaded Media Files" in Android

Tags: android, encryption, virtualfilesystem

I need to download and save any type of media file (i.e .mp3, .mp4 etc) in an external storage which cannot be read from any other application other than my own. 
Encryption and Decryption is really slow, it takes 23-27 seconds to encrypt a file of 6MB and decryption takes almost the same time and waiting 23 seconds to start listening a downloaded song is not good. So I had a thought that creating your own VFS (Virtual File System) with CRUD methods might do the trick, so any guidelines to how to implement a VFS or any other solution which will improve the processing time, will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If encryption is that slow, you messed up the crypto code. Even on mobile devices decrypting a 6 MB file should take less than a second.

Comment: @CodesInChaos sorry for the late response, I have followed this tutorial http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/08/encryption-decryption-in-android.html 
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This code uses an 8 byte buffer. I suggest increasing it to 2048 bytes or so.

Comment: If you care about actual security, you should investigate which modes of encryption are suitable, if you need a MAC and how to use an IV. But it sounds like you barely need more than obfuscation. If you need read access to the middle of the file, CTR mode is a bit nicer than CBC, but you absolutely need to make sure to use a proper per file IV. If you need write access to the middle of the file, things get very complicated, so I'd avoid that whenever possible.